# Nested AND Sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js

I have a Booking table to which I would like to recover only all the bookings of a coach, but on a certain date AND with the status (boolean = true).

In my Booking table, I have a coach who only has a reservation, but the request also gets me the hours of the other coaches

My request:

```
 Booking.findAll({
            attributes: ['booked_time'],
            where: {
                fk_id_coach: coachId,
                [Op.and]: {
                    booked_date: fullDate,
                    [Op.and]: {
                        status: true
                    }
                }

            }
        }).then(results => {
            return res.json({
                results
            })
```

This request returns me all the hours reserved of each coach ... I would like only to check the reserved time of A coach on a precise date AND with the status = true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need of nested and query for that , you can simply do that like this

```
Booking.findAll({
    attributes: ['booked_time'],
    where: {
        fk_id_coach: coachId,
        booked_date: fullDate,
        status: true
    }
}).then(results => { return res.json({results} )
```

And if its still not working , please post your raw query so we can debug it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Vivek Doshi, I found other solution:

```
 coach.getBookings({
            attributes: ['booked_time'],
            where: {
                booked_date: fullDate,
                [Op.and]: {
                    status: true
                }
            }
```

Better way with associations, I did not think about it
 :p